# Basic Java: Method to tell if a double is an integer

Tags: java, int, double, isinteger

I'm a beginning programmer and I need a method that returns whether or not a double is an integer. The problem occurs when the number is too big for an int to hold.

Here's what I have:

```
private static boolean isInteger(double n){
    int ni = (int) n;
    double nd = (double) ni;
    if (nd==n)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Say I put in like 143215890634.0. It will return false because the int can't store that many digits.

How can I allow the int(or another class) to store more digits or is there a better way to determine if a double is an int without comparing like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `long` holds more digits than `int`. By the time you get outside the range of `long`, *all* `double` values are integers (and separated by more than 1). So you could use something like:

```
private static boolean isInteger(double n) {
    if (n > (double) Long.MAX_VALUE ||  n < (double) Long.MIN_VALUE) {
        return true;
    }
    long asLong = (long) n;
    return n == (double) asLong;
}
```

There are alternative approaches which would determine the bitwise representation, and check the exponent - but they'd be more complicated, at least to understand.

Note that checking for *exact* values in binary floating point is usually a bad idea. You might instead want to check how close the `double` to the nearest integer, and have some sort of tolerance.

Comment: What do you mean by this - By the time you get outside the range of long, all double values are integers (and separated by more than 1) ?

Comment: @davidblaine See [Section 4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1) and [Section 4.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3) of the JLS for some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
boolean isInteger(double d) {
    return d % 1 == 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel that this is the easiest to understand and the most elegant way of doing it. Its language independent too. +1 for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

**Compare it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.** If it is smaller - it will fit into integer assuming it has no fraction.

Answer (score 0):

To store lager numbers you would have to use `long` instead. As for the comparison, you could maybe do `num == Math.round(num)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, this would work even better than Math.round(), since it avoids type promotion:

```
    double d1 = 143215890634.0, d2 = 143215890634.001;
    System.out.println(d1 == Math.floor(d1));
    System.out.println(d2 == Math.floor(d2));
```

This works, if with "integer" you don't mean actual type "int", but a "number without position after decimal point".